# c++ read 3 columns from a text file into a 2D array or 3 individual arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++

I have a text file looks like this:

```
173865.385  444879.102  0.299
173864.964  444879.137  0.467
173864.533  444879.177  0.612
173864.113  444879.211  0.798
173863.699  444879.244  1.002
173863.27   444879.282  0.926
173862.85   444879.317  0.974
....
....
....(around 200000 rows)
```

I'm trying to put each column into one array.
now I have these cripts:

```
int ReadDataFromFile(double * DataList[] ,int DataListCount,string &FileName)
{
    ifstream DataFile;
    int CurrentDataIndex = 0;;
    DataFile.open(FileName.c_str(),ios::in);
    if(DataFile.is_open()==true)
    {
        char buffer[200];
        while(DataFile.getline(buffer,200))
        {
            string strdata;
            stringstream ss(buffer);
            for(int i =0;i<DataListCount;++i)
            {
                getline(ss,strdata,' ');
                DataList[i][CurrentDataIndex] = strtod(strdata.c_str(),NULL);
            }
            ++CurrentDataIndex;
        }
    }
    return CurrentDataIndex;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    double a[200000],b[200000],c[200000];
    double* DataList[] = {a,b,c};
    int DataCount = ReadDataFromFile(DataList,3,string("D:\\read\\k0_test.txt"));
    for(int i=0;i<DataCount;++i)
    {
        cout<<setw(10)<<a[i]<<setw(10)<<b[i]<<setw(10)<<c[i]<<endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

But it always tell an error "overflow". Is there any other way to relize this problem?

Comment: You can't just allocate 4.8 MB on the stack. Use `double *a = new double[200000]` etc. instead (or better yet, use a vector!)

Comment: Also, is it "around 200000 rows", or "definitely less than 200000 rows", or "possibly more than 200000 rows"?

Comment: I have several text files and they all have around 200000 entries. Some are larger than this (bu not too much), some are less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 double a[200000],b[200000],c[200000];
```

used out all your program's stack space, try to use `std::vector` (preferred) or use dynamic array, which allocates memory on the heap instead.

For example: (for `a` only)

```
vector<double> a;
a.reserve(200000);
```

Or

```
vector<double> a(200000);
```

if use dynamic array:

```
double* a = new double[200000];
```

Don't forget to release memory when you are done using them:

```
delete [] a;
```

See [STL Vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) for more information.

Comment: I'm not really know about how to use vector. Would you mind show me a piece of code in this case? Thank you!

Comment: Yes. So vector is also a type, similar with double, float, etc. Am I understanding it right?

Comment: @user2355225 vector is a sequence STL container that holds int, double, float and other user defined class objects.

Comment: Opps, it doesn't work. Probably there are something else needs to be changed in the code. I'm not sure where.

Comment: @user2355225 when you put elements into vector, use `push_back`, since `reserve`method only allocates memory, but leaves it uninitialized. There is no value for the objects, because nothing is added to the vector. You need push_back to put elements into it. See the `STL vector` link for more information about how to use it

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions:

Move `double a[200000],b[200000],c[200000];` outside the _tmain so that they can be global variables.

Or,

Declare a,b,c as:

```
double *a = new double[200000]; 
double *b = new double[200000]; 
double *c = new double[200000];
```

and don't forget to free them by `delete[]`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you! :) It helps. It didn't crash now.

Comment: But there is problem of my output. Is there anything else needs to be changed in my codeblock? Cause now the results of array "b" is same with "a".